# Limit FPS in Scene view Unity

Tags: unity

Is there a way to limit the FPS in the **Scene view** of Unity?

I tried `Application.targetFrameRate` but this only works in the game view.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about why you want to limit the FPS in the scene view? This may give us clues about what methods will be most appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an FPS limiting script and add [ExecuteInEditMode] to it.

Additionally, you can do it in the Nvidia control panel.

1. Manage 3d settings.
2. Select Unity in the app list.
3. Set the settings: max frame rate = 30/60.

Comment: The Nvidia control panel method did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All in all there are only two solutions to limit FPS for scene view:

1. Re-check vsync in game view every time unity starts || exit game mode (unity bug). By some reason it affects scene view as well
2. Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Ineraction Mode: Monitor Refresh Rate